# How can I block WMTS GetCapabilities Link

Tags: geoserver, layers, wmts, security

I want to block to below link like WMS services.

http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?REQUEST=GetCapabilities

In services, WMS method's has "GetCapabilities" and selected roles only "Admin". When I use this method, User can't display my all layers. I want to same permission for WMTS services.

Comment: First of all: What do you even mean? I kinda interpret this as "I want to disable the GetCapabilities request on my wmts endpoint?". Second: Having to infer that this is in fact Geoserver from the link is not easy.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment, rather than an answer but I don't have enough reputation.
 Anyway, I guess the title is a bit misleading. I don't think he wants to block the GetCapabilities request in general, but to restrict the outcome to show only permitted layers to a particular user. I'm actually seeing the same behavior on my end. The layers are restricted by roles associated to the users. If a user requests the WMS GetCapabilities he will only see the layers he got permission to, but when the user requests the WMTS GetCapabilities it shows all the layers in the GeoServer (even though the user cannot access them because he has no permission). Just make sure that Data Security in Caching Defaults is enabled (that's the GWC Data Security). When enabled, the security works but it can be a bit misleading if all layers are shown to a user by the WMTS GetCapabilities. More on that here (https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/geowebcache/config.html).